# How to pass secret to oidc.json

Tags: keycloak, wildfly, elytron

There is in wildfly [documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Admin_Guide.html#Elytron_OIDC_Client) section with instructions how to setup keycloak oidc authentication. But i don't see how to pass credentials.secret in secure way. I have contenerized wildfly in kubernts. Using env variables seems to be not a secure way. In old wildfly vault could be used. In new there is CredentialStore but i think that I can't use password from credential store in oidc.json. So how are you doing that? Is there any other way, than env variables, to pass secret data to oidc.json?